# How to make variable in Cron

Tags: variables, unix, cron, cron-task

I have cron file working in OS Debian with lines like this:

```
0 0 * * * php -q /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > /var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/log/someDomain.log &
```

Is it possible to create a variable in cron file and put in the path:

```
/var/www/bbs/public_html/worker/
```

And use it in code like this:

```
0 0 * * * php -q $VARIABLE/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > $VARIABLE/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q $VARIABLE/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > $VARIABLE/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q $VARIABLE/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > $VARIABLE/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q $VARIABLE/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > $VARIABLE/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q $VARIABLE/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > $VARIABLE/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q $VARIABLE/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > $VARIABLE/log/someDomain.log &
0 0 * * * php -q $VARIABLE/get.php 'domain=someDomain' < /dev/null > $VARIABLE/log/someDomain.log &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution

```
TESTDIR=/home/user/test

* * * * * $TESTDIR/script.sh
```

Seems it work.